# Finding an oval sink that fits under my granite bathroom counter top

Tags: bathroom, sink, granite

My oval white under counter bathroom sink is cracked and I am trying to find a replacement. The oval cutout in the granite top is 17 7/8" by 12 7/8" while the basin size of the current sink is 19" by 14". It's hard to measure full length and width of the sink without taking it out. I have looked around online and I can't seem to find anything that fits. But I guess I do not need the exact basin size and long as it's not less that the cutout. Does anyone know about something that could fit and where I could get it?

Comment: This question wanders perilously close to a shopping question, so might be off topic for here. But, a real plumbing showroom will be the most logical place to have this conversation. (Bring a full-size cardboard template, not just length/width numbers.)  And if they can't find a good fit, they could find you something bigger and you could have the granite re-cut.

Comment: Thank you. That was a helpfull answer. I looked "everywhere" online and also at Lowe's and Home Depot, so I wanted to ask here, not wanting to know what to buy, but where to get. Off to a plumber showroom I will go! :)